# How to keep transparency of PNG image for ScaleImageLabel?

Tags: codenameone

I've added a PNG with transparent background as MultiImage to a theme and tried to use it for ScaleImageLabel:

```
ScaleImageLabel logoLabel = new ScaleImageLabel(theme.getImage("sign-up--logo.png 1"));
```

The Codename One Designer shows the image as it should be, with transparency:

[image: png with transparent background]

But simulator paints the transparent area white:

[image: png with white background]

What should be done to keep the background of the PNG image transparent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
logoLabel.setUIID("Container");
```

Generally the opacity comes from the `Label` UIID so you can style `Label` to have a transparency value of 0.

Comment: Shai, thanks for reply, but `Label` does have transparency value set to 0. I've double checked this. And I've tried `logoLabel.setUIID("Container");` but got the same result: white color instead of transparent area.
Also, I've created my own style and made sure all settings are set correctly, still the same problem. To me it looks like PNG lost its transparency maybe while resizing.

Comment: Another strange thing is that I've got space on top and bottom of the image (which is also white) but image itself doesn't have the space.

Comment: Yes you are correct, ScaleImageLabel implicitly calls `setBgTransparency(255)` which would make sense for some cases but not all. I'll remove that behavior. You can try calling `setBgTransparency(0)` on the component style but I'm not sure it will work properly as this appears in several places in the code

Comment: Shai, setting Background Transparency as you suggested helped:
`ScaleImageLabel logoLabel = new ScaleImageLabel(theme.getImage("sign-up--logo-2.png"));
        logoLabel.getStyle().setBgTransparency(0);`
Thank you

Comment: Great, this should not be necessary after the next update.